# Python 3 Tkinter appending label to print user input from entry label

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Hey guys I have just started learning about GUI's and in particular just started using tkinter. I have spent hours searching forums for what I believe should be an obvious and simple solution and found a few people asking similar questions but i failed to understand the solutions.
Basically I am just trying to get the user to input a letter with an entry widget and display that on a label when the go button is pressed. If anyone could explain to me how to do this I would be extremely grateful.

Here's the code I have written:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk
import random


root = Tk()
root.title('test')

frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding='3 3 12 12 ')
frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

letter = StringVar()


def gobutton(*args):

    print_label['text'] += letter


print_label = ttk.Label(frame, text="")
print_label.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=N)


letter_entry = ttk.Entry(frame, width=7, textvariable=letter)
letter_entry.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=S)

g_button = ttk.Button(frame, width=7, text='GO', command=gobutton)
g_button.grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=S)

for child in frame.winfo_children():
    child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

letter_entry.focus() #WHAT DOES THIS DO?
root.bind('<Return>', gobutton)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `.get()` what `StringVar` contains when button is clicked.

```
def gobutton(): #if you don't plan to pass any parameters, *args is unnecesarry
    print_label['text'] += letter.get()
```

Also, for this program, using a `StringVar` a little bit overkill. You can easily go for `Entry.get()` to get what entry contains. Below code demonstrates how to use `get()` method with a quite simple(and a little bit dirty) code.

```
def getMethod():
    lbl.configure(text=ent.get())
    #or 
    #lbl["text"] = ent.get()

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Button(root, text="Get Entry", command=getMethod).pack()
ent = tk.Entry(root)
lbl = tk.Label(root, text = "Before click")
lbl.pack()
ent.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

`.focus()` is an alias for [.focus_set()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.focus_set-method) method.

> Moves the keyboard focus to this widget. This means that all keyboard
>   events sent to the application will be routed to this widget.

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough explanation it means a lot to me that you would take the time to help me. This is exactly what I was looking for! Cheers @Lafexios